# Redis Connection on Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis

I have created a redis server on AWS and when i am trying to connect it to my laravel installlation on ec2 instance. I am getting `Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]` error.
I don't know why this is happening. localhost or 127.0.0.1 does not exist in any file. 
`config/database.php` code is

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',
        'clusters' => [
        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ]],

    ],
```

in the `.env` file
i have updated the REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT.

REDIS_PASSWORD is blank.

UPDATE 1

Now i have updated the `config/database.php` to

```
'redis' => [
        'cluster' => false,

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'redis',
            ],

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],
```

Now i am getting `MOVED 3099 AWS_PRIVATE_IP:6379` error

i tried connecting the redis with redis cli. Everything worked. But when i am setting the key i am getting same error in `redis-cli`

Comment: If you keep those options blank in the .env file, the default values will be used. so `'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),` will use localhost as the default value if you don't define one.

Comment: @Sandeesh yes, i know that only password field is blank HOST and POST values are there

Comment: You config file might be cached, Try running `php artisan config:clear`